# How do you avoid NULL when sending DTO?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a DTO with several lists

```
@Data
public class ContributionUpdate<T extends MovieRequest> {
    private Map<Long, T> elementsToAdd;
    private List<T> newElementsToAdd;
    private Map<Long, T> elementsToUpdate;
    private List<Long> idsToDelete;
}
```

When sending an object, some lessons may be NULL. The method operating on these lists looks terrible because of the conditions checking if the message is NULL. https://pastebin.com/niMiYzeg Is there any nice correct way that creates an empty list if the object has a NULL list?

Answer (score 0):

May be Apache `CollectionsUtils` method [emptyIfNull](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#emptyIfNull(java.util.Collection)) will help you:

```
public static <T> Collection<T> emptyIfNull(Collection<T> collection)
```

> Returns an immutable empty collection if the argument is null, or the
>   argument itself otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Reference types in Java are always non-nullable, so in order to reduce bloat checking for null values, you could enforce that your input is valid with `assert` statements.

Your function would then start with something like

```
assert contribution.getElementsToAdd() != null;
assert contribution.getElementsToUpdate() != null;
assert contribution.contribution.getIdsToDelete() != null;
...
```

And then you would be safe to use those functions and be sure that you will have a valid value. The assertion would fail for users in development and tests that send your function an invalid value.

At a certain point, it's a balance between defensive coding and having some point where you say "look, if you give me invalid input, I'm just going to throw an exception".

For your `ContributionUpdate` class, you could initialize each of the maps/lists with empty values in your constructor, so that you don't default to `null` references and hit those assertions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the Lists and Maps final
2. Set them in the constructor (of course).
3. Have use a setter to set the values.

```
     public void setBlammyList(final List newValue)
     {
        blammyList.clear();

        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(newValue))
        {
            blammyList.addAll(newValue);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

You may update your DTO to be something like this:

```
@Data
public class ContributionUpdate<T extends MovieRequest> {
    private Map<Long, T> elementsToAdd = new HashMap<>();
    private List<T> newElementsToAdd = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<Long, T> elementsToUpdate = new HashMap<>();
    private List<Long> idsToDelete = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

But it's probably not a good solution, you'd better updated your service which returns this data to return empty Map or List in case of absence of the data.